# webpack is not finding my imports or converting my es6 code

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

I'm new to webpack and trying to set up for my client side project. I have created a repo over [here](https://github.com/antoaravinth/tm), which has my entire source code.

My webpack config looks like this:

```
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry: './public/js/main.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: './public/dist/bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{ 
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: "babel-loader",
            include: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, "./public/js"),
            ],
            exclude: [
              path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
            ]
        }],
        resolve: {
          extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
        }
    }
};
```

When I run:

```
webpack
```

its bundling my js and putting it to `dist` folder. However, I can see the bundled file is not having `Point.js` or `loadash` that can be found on my `main.js` `imports`. And also looks like the resulted bundle code is not converted to es6 but rather just having the entire content of my `main.js` file.

Where I'm making mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Made following changes in your package json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.7.7",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.0"
}
```

and in webpack.config.js :

```
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
entry: './public/js/main.js',
output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: './public/dist/bundle.js'
},
module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.js$/,
        loaders: ['babel?presets[]=es2015'],
        include: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, "./public/js"),
        ],
        exclude: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
        ]
    }],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    }
}
};
```

Run npm install and the webpack. It should work fine.

Comment: Thanks. But its not finding modules from `node_modules`. Any reason?

Comment: It should definitely find modules from node_modules if you are using 'import' .

Comment: Found the issue :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To complete XtremeCoder's answer, here what I needed to add to webpack.config.js to make it works :

```
module: {
    loaders: [{ 
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        include: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, "./public/js"),
        ],
        exclude: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
        ],
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015']
        }
    }],
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    }
}
```