# React and webpack appropriate loader error

Tags: reactjs, webpack, loader

Hi I'm new in react I just starting to learn reactjs.
I have some problems and i don't know how to fix it.

This is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "5.8.*",
    "babel-loader": "5.3.*",
    "react": "0.13.*",
    "webpack": "1.12.*",
    "webpack-dev-server": "1.10.*"
  }
}
```

webpack.config,js file

```
module.exports = {
    entry: [
        './src/App.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: 'app.js'
    },
    module: {
        loader: [{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            loader: 'babel'
        }]
    }
};
```

and app.js file

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>alo</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

and the error when I run webpack

```
ERROR in ./src/App.js
Module parse failed: C:\Users\mkrtc\Desktop\react\src\App.js Line 1: Unexpected token
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import React from 'react';
|
| class App extends React.Component {
 @ multi main
```

Comment: Typo. It should be `loaders: [...` instead of `loader: [...`

Comment: ok after that give this error

ERROR in ./src/App.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/Users/mkrtc/Desktop/react/src/App.js: Unexpected token (6:3)
  4 |   render() {
  5 |           return (
> 6 |                   <div>
    |                   ^
  7 |                           <h1>alo</h1>
  8 |                   </div>
  9 |           )

Comment: Possibly duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36964724/webpack-is-not-finding-my-imports-or-converting-my-es6-code/36964951#36964951

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33509770/react-babel-webpack-not-parsing-jsx-code

Comment: Install the loader preset to compile react code. [read this, it could help to understand additional configuration for using react babel with webpack](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/08/setting-up-react-for-es6-with-webpack-and-babel-2.html)

Comment: I recommend this tutorial http://survivejs.com/webpack_react/webpack_and_react/   Working source code included.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up your babel configuration. Unlike babel 5, Babel 6 doesn't do anything out of the box. plugins and presets need to set. Create a `.bablerc` file at the root level like this:

```
"presets": [
  "react",
  "stage-0"
],
```

this enables the features from presets [react](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/) and [stage-0](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-0/)